# Print IFrame in ie10 doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, iframe, printing

I am trying to print a dynamically created iframe in IE10. It neither throws error nor works. Below is my code.

```
function PrintVisitSlip() {
    var f = document.getElementById('frmPrintVisitSlip');
    var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
    ifrm.src = 'about:blank';
    ifrm.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
    var _styleCSS = '<style type="text/css">p{border-bottom: white;}.Head{font-size: 9pt;font-weight: bold;}'
        + 'td{border-bottom: 1px solid black;height: 8px;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;margin: 0 0 0 0;font-size: 7pt;padding: 1px 0 1px 0;}'
        + '.LC{width: 125px;text-align: left;padding-left: 4px;}.RC{width: 21px;text-align: right;padding-right: 3px;}'
        + '.LC1{width: 80px;text-align: left;padding-left: 4px;font-size: 6.5pt;}.RC1{width: 18px;text-align: right;}</style>';
    ifrm.contentWindow.document.open('text/html', 'replace');
    ifrm.contentWindow.document.write(_styleCSS + f.outerHTML);
    ifrm.contentWindow.document.close();
    var iw = ifrm.contentWindow || ifrm;
    iw.focus();
    iw.print();
    return false;
}
```

This code works fine in chrome. But in IE10 I doesn't see any print window populating on click of print button.

Comment: Can you very there is no error in your script? Maybe you have an IE specific error, and that's why you get no print. Press F12 to open the webdev and go to _Console_ to see any script errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try printing it when `readyState` of the `iframe`'s document is `complete`, as `open.write` is async under IE. Moreover, `ifrm.style.display = "none"` prevents the frame from being printed, so the whole window gets printed instead.

The following code has been verified with IE10. It may not work with other browsers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>main</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <script>
        function Go() {
            var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");

            ifrm.src = 'about:blank';
            ifrm.style.borderWidth = 0;
            ifrm.style.width = 0;
            ifrm.style.height = 0;

            document.body.appendChild(ifrm);

            ifrm.contentWindow.document.open("text/html", "replace");

            ifrm.contentWindow.document.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (ifrm.contentWindow.document.readyState === "complete") {
                    ifrm.contentWindow.document.body.onafterprint = function () {
                        ifrm.removeNode(true);
                    }
                    ifrm.contentWindow.document.body.focus();
                    ifrm.contentWindow.print();
                }
            }

            ifrm.contentWindow.document.write("<b>Hello</b>, world!");
            ifrm.contentWindow.document.close();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="Go()">Go</button>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't understand your edit. Did you update the code to be correct or did you leave the incorrect code? This is confusing.  And why are there two paragraphs of Javascript that look like almost the same thing?

Comment: @Richard, I've cleaned up the answer.